# Lomb-Scargle negative power and Response time

Tags: frequency-response, periodogram

I have response time (RT) data (values between 0 and 3) to a memory task. Participants made a response at about every 9.5sec with several breaks of 25sec. I want to analyse the whole timeseries of (RT), which yield at about 30 datapoints.

Due to the unequal distances between samples, I took the Lomb-Scargle periodogram. This plot shows this result (each line is one subject.The vertical blue line is at Freq = 0.105 (9.5sec)):
[image]

I'm wondering what do the negative power mean?

Do you think it is ok to take Lomb-Scargle for response times?